# jQuery mobile changing default mobile keyboard on form inputs

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I am working on a jQuery Mobile form right now and when I view it from an android or iPhone the keyboard seems to pull up strange.  Even though I have a few input fields whenever I select a field the keyboard that pops up shows the "go" option instead of the "next" option.  Does anyone know how to change the setting so when there are still fields that need to be filled in the next option on the keyboard is displayed instead on the go or done option?

This is the code I am using:

```
<form name="form1" action="test.php" method="POST">

<div id="page1" data-role="page" class="type-interior">    
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Contact Info<div id="fixErrors"></div></h1>
    <a href="#page2" data-role="button" id="btnPage2" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="arrow-r">Next</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">

    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="group1">
    <label style="font-weight:bold; float:right;">* = optional field</label>   
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="req" maxlength="60" tabindex="1"/>
        </div>


        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="req" maxlength="60" tabindex="2"/>
        </div>


        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="address">Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="address" name="address" class="req" maxlength="90"/>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
    <a href="#page2" data-role="button" id="btnPage2">Next</a>

</div>
</div>

<div id="page2" data-role="page">    
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
    <h1>Personal Information<div id="fixErrors"></div></h1>
    <a href="#page3" data-role="button" id="btnPage3" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="arrow-r">Next</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="group2">
    <label style="font-weight:bold; float:right;">All fields required</label>          
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
           <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
              <legend>Gender:</legend>
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="female"/>
                  <label for="female">Female</label>

                  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male"/>
                  <label for="male">Male</label>
           </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
           <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
              <legend>Are you a CNA?</legend> 
                  <input type="radio" name="cna" value="Yes" id="cnaY"/>
                  <label for="cnaY">Yes</label>

                  <input type="radio" name="cna" value="No" id="cnaN"/>
                  <label for="cnaN">No</label>
           </fieldset>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
    <a href="#page3" data-role="button" id="btnPage3">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: have you added [`tabindex`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)?

Comment: yes I have with no luck :-(

Comment: on iPhone it works fine. I dont know about Android. Anyway, you shouldn't wrap pages in `form`, wrap form elements.